# Avoid skipping before environment

Tags: spacing, environments

I'm having trouble handling vertical space with my custom environments. I noticed that 
using `\unskip` *after* the environment eliminates that space, but I have found now solution for the space *before* the environment.

My definition is as follows (I'm using the `enumitem` package):

```
\newenvironment*{ejemplo}[1][]%
  {%
  \begin{enumerate}%
    [%
    nolistsep,%
    topsep=0pt,%
    rightmargin=0pt,%
    leftmargin=1.5\parindent,%
    parsep=.5\baselineskip,%
    align=left,
    ]%
    \item[#1]%
  }
  {%
  \end{enumerate}%
  \unskip%
  }
```

Any ideas on how to avoid that previous vspace?

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  I attempted to reproduce the problem and was not able to with a basic test case.

Comment: Yes, you have a point.  I can't reproduce the problem either in a MWE. It seems to be a problem of my big document. I'll check and see.

Answer (score 2):

You've set `parsep` twice.  Remove the second occurence `parsep=.5\baselineskip`

Comment: You're right. I've deleted the first one in the question. Cheers!